# Why do I have to enter "sudo chmod -R 0777 folder1" repeatedly if some new folder is created inside folder1

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel

I have to give access to some launcher inside "folder1".
Whenever a new folder is created inside "folder1", I have to again give the permissions by typing `sudo chmod -R 0777 folder1`. Is there a way that I could permanently enable `0777` for a particular folder. No matter how many new subfolders are created inside it.

I tried and it works. But I have to give the permissions again and again

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 folder1
```

Comment: what default permission do you want ,and pls post the out put of   ```stat folder1```  and ```umask```

Comment: and if the new folder is created by another application other than yourself, include that info

Answer (score -1):

You need to umask command in your ".profile" file in your home path. Then restart your session and create new folder. All the folders will get fill permission by default for all users.
Command $ `umask 000`

1. Open .profile file
2. Insert command "umask 000" in .profile file and save it.
3. Restart the session and create folders.

Answer (score -1):

I will try setfacl to set ACLs, e.g.:

setfacl -m d:o::7,d:g::7,d:o::7 mydir/

setfacl -m o::7,g::7,o::7 mydir/

Actually, this way if you create directories under mydir they will have 0777 permissions and files will have 0666.

Hope it is useful

Cheers